# apache camel file filter starting with a specific format

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying to read files from one folder to another folder. I am using Apache Camel for the same. the basic configuration as below is

```
from("file:/testfolder/out/")
    .routeId("testRoute")
    .to("file:/testfolder/in/")
    .end();
```

I am trying to add filters using include to pick only specific format starting with test_files as below:

```
from("file:/testfolder/out/?include=test_files*")
    .routeId("testRoute")
    .to("file:/testfolder/in/")
    .end();
```

the above include is not working.

I tried using GenericFileFilter as below:

```
@Component
public class TestFileFilter implements GenericFileFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(GenericFile file) {
        if (file.getFileName().matches("^[test_files]"))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I bind this TestFileFilter in custom Route class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`include=test_files.*` did not work because of a regex mismatch. Add a `.` before the `*` in include as shown below:

```
from("file:/testfolder/out/?include=test_files.*")
    .routeId("testRoute")
    .to("file:/testfolder/in/")
    .end();
```

To use a custom filter, i followed this article: https://help.talend.com/reader/SUzvVjxkFWs4p6BXVXwyHQ/uqoSuaP4sXgDRWPG4JSPvA

Define a bean in the route class:

```
@Bean
    TestFileFilter testFileFilter() {
        return new TestFileFilter();
    }
```

And then modify your route as shown below:

```
from("file:/testfolder/out/?filter=#testFileFilter")
    .routeId("testRoute")
    .to("file:/testfolder/in/")
    .end();
```